# Why am I getting this message: Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net, casting, compiler-errors

Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace businessTMS
{
    public class SignIn
    {
        public string authenticate(String UserName, String password)
        {  
            dataTMS.SignIn data = new dataTMS.SignIn();
          string authenticate=(string)data.authenticate(UserName, password);
            return authenticate;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice code snippet you have there, but what's your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your dataTMS.SignIn authenticate method is for sure returning a boolean.  Any reason why you are returning a string in your businessTMS?  If so, what string are you trying to push back to the UI?  "Logged On" versus "Not Logged In"?  Why string?  and not just pass it along as boolean (public bool authenticate(...) ?

Comment: @Simucal: good re-tag, I was just about to do that as well!

Comment: Though it is a compiler error, not an exception.

Answer (score 18):

Your error is occurring due to this line:

```
string authenticate = (string)data.authenticate(UserName, password);
```

You are setting authenticate equal to a true/false calculation which is returning a Boolean value.  Try this instead.

```
string authenticate = data.authenticate(UserName, password).ToString();
```

You can also modify the code to still return a string by doing this:

```
bool authenticate = data.authenticate(UserName, password);
return authenticate.ToString();
```

**PREFERRED OPTION:**
Furthermore, I'm not sure why you are returning a string representation of true/false (bool)...  If it were my function, I would probably return this:

```
return data.authenticate(UserName, password);
```

I would highly encourage you to simply return the Boolean value in the PREFERRED OPTION area.  There is no obvious reason to keep this in a string format.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Boolean.ToString Method (documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atahsch6.aspx)) like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace businessTMS
{
    public class SignIn
    {
        public string authenticate(String UserName, String password)
        {  
            dataTMS.SignIn data = new dataTMS.SignIn();

            return data.authenticate(UserName, password).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error message "Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'string'" but the line in my code where the error appeared was not cause of the message.

I had inadvertently chopped the last parameter off the previous lines function call, which should have been a bool, and not closed the bracket.